# Select Rows Within X Dates Of Today

Tags: google-sheets

I have an ordered list of upcoming birthdays and anniversaries (2 columns)
How can I create another list from that of only rows within X days of today
Both X days before and X days after today

```
8/14/2023   Person 1 (26)  
8/18/2023   Person 2 (15)  
9/29/2023   Person 3 (44)  
10/3/2023   Person 4 (4)  
10/26/2023  Person 5 (13)  
11/6/2023   Person 6 (13)  
11/11/2023  Person 7 (2)  
11/12/2023  Person 8 Anniversary (40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a filter or a query:

```
=filter(A2:B,A2:A>=today()-8,A2:A<=today()+8)
```

or

```
=query(A1:B,"select * where A>=date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A<=date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1 )
```

[image]

I have added extra rows so that it picks up two people on 20th July 2023.

Comment: Thank you! The query worked well for my use.